# How to exit true from a heredoc command from MYSQL?

Tags: bash, shell, mysql

I have a script that exits on error using set -e and I can't figure out how to force it to return true despite || true

```
#!/bin/bash

        mysql -h localhost -D test -ppassword <<-RENAME
                SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
                RENAME TABLE $table TO $table\_keep;
                SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
        RENAME
```

I've tried using || true to no avail, it throws mysql into interactive mode

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
        mysql -h localhost -D test -ppassword || true <<-RENAME
                SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
                RENAME TABLE $table TO $table\_keep;
                SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
        RENAME
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

It should be as simple as

```
set -e
mysql -h localhost -D test -ppassword  <<-RENAME || true
      SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
      RENAME TABLE $table TO $table\_keep;
      SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
RENAME
```

or you could put it in an if statement

```
set -e
if mysql -h localhost -D test -ppassword  <<-RENAME
      SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
      RENAME TABLE $table TO $table\_keep;
      SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
RENAME
then
    echo mysql was happy
else
    rc=$?
    echo mysql returned $rc
    : do something with $rc
fi
```

Note that a `if condition ; then stuff; else stuff ; fi` will return true at the `fi` although the `set -e` can cause the script to invoke its error handling (normally exit) if the `stuff` has a non-zero exit.